Stochastic Convergence of $\sqrt{n}\cdot \min\{X_1,\dots,X_n\} \rightarrow 0$ with $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim \exp(\lambda)$
Exercise:
I want to show that $ \sqrt{n} Y_n $ converges stochastically to $0$, i.e., for every $\varepsilon > 0$
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left( |\sqrt{n} Y_n - 0| \geq \varepsilon \right) = 0.
$$
where $ Y_n := \min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\} $, where $ X_i \sim \exp(\lambda) , i.i.d. \forall i=1,\dots,n$
My Question:
I wanted to just eliminate the absolute values by saying the term cannot be negative, but then I had my doubts, so it is most probably a silly question but can I really say that all $X_i \geq 0$ because they are exponentially distributed and thus it follows that $Y_n \geq 0$?
Because I saw once a proof in which it was written that for an exponential random variable: $X \geq 0$ almost surely.
By definition of the exponential distribution density function, of course, negative values have no probability mass weighted to them, but does this really strictly imply that an exponential random variable can never be negative or is it possible but only with a probability of zero?

Some important information is missing. Can you guess what is missing?

important information regarding the question if for $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$ the definition is $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ and thus leaving the absolute values out of it? No, there is no info missing to answer this? I think you did not understand the question then?

I think what geetha is referring to is: are the $X_i$ independent or do they have some other dependency structure that you should specify?

Why the downvote ? The op has a doubt regarding positivity and almost sure positivity. I don't understand what is with this downvoting trend.  @Sgt.Slothrop Yes, an exponential variable can be negative but that only happens with $0$ probability. So when $P(X\in B)$ can be written as $P(X\in B, X\geq 0)$ as $P(X\geq 0)=1$ for any set (Borel set) $B\subseteq \Bbb{R}$. When something happens with probability $0$, we often ignore that all together and say things like "this is postive almost surely".

@Wei Op has already mentioned that $X_{i}$'s are iid

An exponential random variable is positive(non-negative) with probability $1$. An exponential variable can be negative but that only happens with 0
probability. So $P(X∈B)$ can be written as $P(X∈B,X≥0)$ as $P(X≥0)=1$
for any set (Borel set) $B\subseteq \Bbb{R}$. When something happens with probability $0$, we often ignore that all together and say things like this does not happen almost surely.
\begin{align}P(\min(X_{1},...,X_{n})>\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}})&=P(X_{1}>\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}},...,X_{n}>\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}})\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{n}P(X_{k}>\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}})\\&=P(X_{1}>\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}})^{n}\end{align}
And for exponential $\lambda$ variate, $P(X>k)=e^{-\lambda k}$.
So $P(X_{1}>\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}})^{n}=\exp(-\frac{\lambda\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}})^{n}=\exp(-\lambda\epsilon\sqrt{n})\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$.
This shows that $\sqrt{n}\cdot\min(X_{1},...,X_{n})\xrightarrow{P} 0$
Also, you can work a bit harder to get almost sure convergence as $P(\sqrt{n}\min(X_{1},...,X_{n})>\epsilon)$ is summable in $n$ for each fixed $\epsilon>0$.

You can eliminate the absolute value because you want to evaluate probability of this event. You can write it like $\mathbb{P}(|\sqrt{n}Y_n|>\varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}Y_n>\varepsilon, Y_n\geq0)+\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{n}Y_n>\varepsilon, Y_n<0) = \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}Y_n>\varepsilon, Y_n>0) = \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}Y_n>\varepsilon) $ because $\mathbb{P}(Y_n<0)=0$.
But in case of independent random variables you can go other way.
If $X_i\sim Exp(\lambda_i), i=1,\dots,n$ are independent then  $$Y_n=\min{(X_1,\dots,X_n)}\sim Exp(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i)$$
$\mathbb{P}(Y_n\leq x) = \mathbb{P}(\min{(X_1,\dots,X_n)} \leq x) = 1-\mathbb{P}(\min{(X_1,\dots,X_n)} > x) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X_1> x, \dots, X_n > x) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X_1 > x)\mathbb{P}(X_2> x)\dots\mathbb{P}(X_n> x) = 1-e^{-\lambda_1x}\dots e^{-\lambda_nx} = 1-e^{-(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i)x}$
In your case if $X_i, i=1\dots,n$ are i.i.d., $X_i\sim Exp(\lambda), i=1,\dots,n$ then $$Y_n\sim Exp(n\lambda)$$
So, $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}Y_n\leq x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(Y_n\leq \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}((1-e^{-\sqrt{n}\lambda x})\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)) = \chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$$
$\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ is CDF of zero constant. We showed that our sequence $\sqrt{n}Y_n$ goes to zero constant in distribution. Convergence in distribution to constant implies convergence in probability.

Sorry, lost the minus. Thank you.
